# Finding certain data frames in a list and combining those data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe

I have a list of 26 data frames called score.list and I have written a code that tells me which data frames are not complete. So this code gives me the name of the data frame within the list, but it doesn't tell me the index of the data frame in the list.

Example... the code tells me that a data frame named p08 and another data frame named p18 are not complete. Therefore, they need to combined with whichever data frame that follows after these. So if the data frame named `p08` is `score.list[[8]]`, then it should be combined with `score.list[[9]]`. It should replace `[[8]]` with the newly made data frame then `score.list[[9]]` should be deleted from the list.

I'm guessing something like the code below may work to combine & replace a data frame... I'm not sure if the following code works..

```
score.list[[8]] <- rbind(score.list[[8]], score.list[[9]])
```

This is what I tried doing... but didn't exactly work because it didn't make a new data frame after combining it. And I get this error message:

```
Error in if (names(score.list[i]) == names(score.list[i + 1])) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

for(i in 1:length(score.list)){
  if(names(score.list[i])==names(score.list[i+1])) {
    a <- score.list[i]
    b <- score.list[i+1]
    score.list[[i]] <- rbind(a, b)
    print(score.list[[i]])
  }  
}
```

Reason I wrote `if(names(score.list[i]==names(score.list[i+1]))` as that is because the names of the data frames that need to be combined together are the same in the list. The data frame that is not complete has the same name as the one that follows it. So name of the data frame `score.list[[8]]` is same as the name of the data frame `score.list[[9]]`.

Please let me know if there are confusing parts.. I tried to write it as clear as I can. Thank you!

Comment: when modifying your list in place remember the indices change, might be easier to just have your checking function return the indices of the incomplete data.frames and then create a new list with those merged that need merging

Comment: Hmm okay. How do I find the index of the data frame from just knowing the name of the data frame?

Comment: you can use `which()` and match against names in list

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

```
## a list example 
score.list <- 
list(l1= data.frame(x=1),
     l2=data.frame(x=2),
     l3= data.frame(x=3))
## use %in% to select some elements 
## here I am selecting list l1 and l3
do.call(rbind,
   score.list[names(score.list) %in% c('l1','l3')])
```